# creating a responsive form within NetSuite

Tags: forms, netsuite

custom forms within NetSuite require the use of field tags like NLFORM and NLCATEGORY, etc. However it's unclear to me how to incorporate these tags properly into the template of a responsive form so it works.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<Title>General Contact Form</Title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
h1, p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</head>

<Body>
<div class="container">
<h1>
<center>Submit a Message</center>
</h1>
 <form class="form-horizontal">
<NLFORM>
<br>
<fieldset>
<legend>How Can We Help You?</legend>
<div class="form-group">
<p class="control-label col-sm-2">Type of Inquiry*</p>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<NLCATEGORY>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<p class="control-label col-sm-2">Subject*</p>
<div class="col-sm-10"><NLTITLE> </div></div>
<div class="form-group">
<p class="control-label col-sm-2">Message*</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><NLINCOMINGMESSAGE> </div></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="NLFILE">File Upload</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><NLFILE> </div></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Contact Information</legend>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first-name">First Name*</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<NLFIRSTNAME></div></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for ="NLLASTNAME">Last Name*</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><NLLASTNAME></div></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="NLEMAIL">E-mail*</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><NLEMAIL> </div></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="NLPHONE">Phone</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><NLPHONE> </div></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="NLCOUNTRY">Country</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><NLCOUNTRY> </div></div>
</fieldset>


<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> - or - 
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="page_reset(); return false;"></div></div>
<NLSUBSIDIARY>
<br>
<p align=center>Fields marked with an<img src="http://shopping.na2.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=35211&c=4382721&h=2eef11083f182592e0bb">are required.</p>

</form>


</Body>

</HTML>
```

the form fields do respond to resizing the browser window, but NetSuite is not able to properly create a record using this particular form. can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here!?

here's the form URL: http://www.boxcomponents.com/support-form

NetSuite Field Tags are controlled from within the UI; so field width is fixed and doesn't accept percentages; there are also drop-down menus which have a fixed width, which is mildly annoying. I can't seem to get the form to respond properly without removing all of NetSuite's tags.

Comment: Can you provide more details on "not able to properly create a record"? Are you getting errors or messages of any kind? Records being created incorrectly? Or nothing at all?

Comment: no error messages come up; it isn't able to create a record. upon submission of the form, the data entered just reappears on the page. it's not the preferred outcome at all. if you want to see for yourself, just go here: http://www.boxcomponents.com/support-form

Answer (score 2):

What you'll need to do is process the form with script when it opens. Add a script tag after the `</form>` tag to add and remove classes from the form elements.

Also this is redundant and you'll end up with some sort of broken form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<NLFORM>
```

So for instance you'd just have:

```
<NLFORM>
   ...
</form>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $("#main_form").addClass('form-horizontal');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked brilliantly. Do you know if I am stuck with the pre-set field width formatting that NetSuite has for its custom forms? Or can I somehow modify the fields to look differently? the form is now posted here: http://www.boxcomponents.com/contact-us

Comment: You can do almost anything with enough css and script :-) I did however get so frustrated with Netsuite's forms that I ended up creating my own form receiving that does most of the useful background processing that Netsuite's form handler does but which allows more modern processing with fewer hacks. It's Suitebundle #141427. It's only for leads and customers though so wouldn't help in your case.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to convert customer information from a case (anonymous customer) to a contact?

Comment: Yes it's possible. That'd be worthy of a new question though.