# Trying to Align and make Responsive an Online Form in Netsuite (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, netsuite

I've been trying to design an Online form for our customers to upload their prescriptions. I've created the below in Dreamweaver, I'm not a programmer as you will see below but I've given it my shot to make this work and probably added too many things then needed lol. I just followed some of the online tutorials and probably messed up somewhere.

If you run the link at the bottom, you will see it's misaligned (Top, the 'please enter you details text and the form fields'). I've tried padding it quite a lot and of course responsive doesn't work).

I hope you can help. (I apologise if I posted this in the wrong section).

```css
table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
}

.topnav {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fields {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  text-align: left text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#column_container {
  width: 837px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <table width="900" cellpadding="30">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="http://www.medicalsupplydepot.com"><img src="http://themedicalsupplydepot.com/email/logo.jpg" width="183" height="95" alt="Medical Supply Depot"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="javascript:popUpUru('https://sealinfo.verisign.com/splash?form_file=fdf/splash.fdf&dn=secure.medicalsupplydepot.com&amp;lang=en')" title="Click to Verify - This site chose Symantec SSL for secure e-commerce and confidential communications."><img src="https://secure.medicalsupplydepot.com/site/img/verisign_l.gif" alt="Norton SECURED Powered by VeriSign"></a>
          <br>
          <a style="padding-left: 3px;" href="https://www.mcafeesecure.com/RatingVerify?ref=www.medicalsupplydepot.com"><img src="https://images.scanalert.com/meter/www.medicalsupplydepot.com/13.gif" alt="McAfee SECURE sites help keep you safe from identity theft, credit card fraud, spyware, spam, viruses and online scams" oncontextmenu="alert('Copying Prohibited by Law - McAfee Secure is a Trademark of McAfee, Inc.'); return false;"
              border="0" height="54" width="94"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="200">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="http://themedicalsupplydepot.com/email/telephone.jpg" width="29" height="29"></td>
                <td style="font-size:21px; font-weight:bold; color:#536f86">(800) 965-7496</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="http://themedicalsupplydepot.com/email/clock.jpg" width="29" height="29"></td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#333333; padding-top:4px">Monday through Friday, <br>9am to 9pm (Eastern Time)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="http://themedicalsupplydepot.com/email/contact.jpg" width="29" height="29"></td>
                <td style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;"><a href="mailto:info@medicalsupplydepot.com">info@medicalsupplydepot.com</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br><br>
          <NLFORM>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table><br></div>
<br /><br />
<div class="fields" id="fields">
  <h2>Please fill in the details:</h2>
  <table width="100" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <nlsalutation></nlsalutation>
      </td>
      <td>
        <nladdress1></nladdress1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <nlfirstname></nlfirstname>
      </td>
      <td>
        <nladdress2></nladdress2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <nllastname></nllastname>
      </td>
      <td>
        <nladdress3></nladdress3>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <nlemail></nlemail>
      </td>
      <td>
        <nlstate></nlstate>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <nlphone></nlphone>
      </td>
      <td>
        <nlzipcode></nlzipcode>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <nlfile></nlfile>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <nlcomments></nlcomments>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the actual form [Online Form](https://forms.na2.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl/compid.822523/.f?formid=77&h=AACffht_hzTbSAY_pN_FbFu_Y3v9R5fcs5A&whence=&redirect_count=1&did_javascript_redirect=T). The fields added are part of the Netsuite system so they won't show up on Dreamweaver or Notepad++, or whatever else you guys use.

Comment: You'll just need to work with `@media min-width` and `@media max-width` in your CSS. Use this as a guide https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Alternatively, use https://getbootstrap.com/ or another framework that handles responsive grids already. You'll love working with it, especially Bootstrap as you can use `form-group`.

Comment: I'm not sure If I can add bootstrap to Netsuite. Netsuite uses a really old html system.

Comment: https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/loading-custom-html-and-bootstrap-within-a-suitelet-form/ this should help.

Comment: I started to work on making your form responsive without any framework and came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926777/creating-a-responsive-form-within-netsuite. Looks like the question is answered here.

Comment: Wow, that sir looks complicated. I've said in my OP, that I'm not a developer and just used some tutorials online - This to me seems like I need to learn quite a lot to be able to do two things. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have a look at that form, probably steal some coding too. Their form doesn't work so I would have to create it within my own system. Thanks, Dude.

Comment: No, worries. I am not familiar with Netsuite, so when you add the form can you add anything in the `<head>` of the page?

Comment: I'm not sure. All I have is an HTML box to write whatever I want. I thought it would be easy but spent far too long on this :( BTW it's saying to avoid extended discussions and try to move to chat but I don't have enough REP to do that. Don't want to get us in trouble. I didn't expect an answer/help this soon as I was about to turn in for the night. I appreciate it and let you know tomorrow how things turn out. Thanks again

Comment: I'll add an answer in a little while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `HTML` I have added the minimum amount of `CSS` to make this responsive and keep in line your inputs. Also, added `CSS` to allow you to control style of each element. I still recommend finding a method for adding a framework (https://getbootstrap.com/ is my favourite) to your NetSuite pages. This will most likely suffice, but won't evolve with new screens and devices in the same way a popular framework would with updates.

Anyhow, let me know how you go with this and if you have any questions, just ask.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #f9fafb;
}


/* FONT STYLES */

* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #193652;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}


/* GRID */

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.row [class^="col"] {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5rem 2%;
  min-height: 0.125rem;
}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5,
.col-6,
.col-7,
.col-8,
.col-9,
.col-10,
.col-11,
.col-12 {
  width: 96%;
}

.col-1-sm {
  width: 4.33%;
}

.col-2-sm {
  width: 12.66%;
}

.col-3-sm {
  width: 21%;
}

.col-4-sm {
  width: 29.33%;
}

.col-5-sm {
  width: 37.66%;
}

.col-6-sm {
  width: 46%;
}

.col-7-sm {
  width: 54.33%;
}

.col-8-sm {
  width: 62.66%;
}

.col-9-sm {
  width: 71%;
}

.col-10-sm {
  width: 79.33%;
}

.col-11-sm {
  width: 87.66%;
}

.col-12-sm {
  width: 96%;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.hidden-sm {
  display: none;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 33.75em) {
  /* 540px */
  .container {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 45em) {
  /* 720px */
  .col-1 {
    width: 4.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 12.66%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 21%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 29.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 37.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 46%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 54.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 62.66%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 71%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 79.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 87.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 96%;
  }
  .hidden-sm {
    display: block;
  }
  .hidden-lg {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer-text {
    text-align: left !important;
    padding: 13px 0;
  }
  input[type="submit"] {
    float: right !important;
    width: 200px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 60em) {
  /* 960px */
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 60rem;
  }
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e3ed;
  background: #fff;
}

.sec-images {
  text-align: center;
}

.sec-images img {
  height: 45px
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}

li.phone {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #536f86;
  height: 35px;
}

li.phone:before {
  content: url(http://themedicalsupplydepot.com/email/telephone.jpg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li.hours {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  height: 35px;
}

li.hours:before {
  content: url(http://themedicalsupplydepot.com/email/clock.jpg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li.email {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 2.7;
}

li.email:before {
  content: url(http://themedicalsupplydepot.com/email/contact.jpg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* FOOTER */

footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9e3ed;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.footer-text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 13px 0;
}

.footer-images {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-images img {
  height: 45px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* FORM */

label {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #536f86;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"] {
  border: 1px solid #d9e3ed;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #193652;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

select {
  border: 1px solid #d9e3ed;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #193652;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 99%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="textarea"]:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #9d2a31 !important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
  outline: none!important;
}

input[type="textarea"] {
  border: 1px solid #d9e3ed;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #193652;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 95%;
}

input[type="file"] {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #193652;
  width: 95%;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #9d2a31;
  float: left;
  width: 99%
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6-sm col-3">
        <img src="http://themedicalsupplydepot.com/email/logo.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 hidden-sm sec-images">
        <img src="https://secure.medicalsupplydepot.com/site/img/verisign_l.gif"><br>
        <img src="https://images.scanalert.com/meter/www.medicalsupplydepot.com/13.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6-sm col-3">
        <ul>
          <li class="phone">(800) 965-7496</li>
          <li class="hours">Monday through Friday,<br>9am to 9pm (Eastern Time)</li>
          <li class="email">info@medicalsupplydepot.com</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2>Please fill in the details:</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-6">
          <!-- Replace <nlsalutation></nlsalutation>-->
          <label>Mr/Mrs</label>
          <input type="text">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nlfirstname></nlfirstname>-->
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nllastname></nllastname>-->
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nlemail></nlemail>-->
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nlphone></nlphone>-->
          <label>Phone Number</label>
          <input type="number">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nlfile></nlfile>-->
          <label>File</label>
          <input type="file">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nlcomments></nlcomments>-->
          <label>Comments</label>
          <input type="textarea">
          <!-- End Replace -->

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-6">
          <!-- Replace <nladdress1></nladdress1>-->
          <label>Address line 1</label>
          <input type="text">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nladdress2></nladdress2>-->
          <label>Address line 2</label>
          <input type="text">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nladdress3></nladdress3>-->
          <label>Address line 3</label>
          <input type="text">
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nlstate></nlstate>-->
          <label>State</label>
          <select name="cars">
            <option value="option1">Option1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option2</option>
            <option value="option3">Option3</option>
            <option value="option4">Option4</option>
          </select>
          <!-- End Replace -->

          <!-- Replace <nlzipcode></nlzipcode>-->
          <label>Zip/Postal Code</label>
          <input type="text">
          <!-- End Replace -->

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <input type="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12-sm footer-text">
        © 2017 Medical Supply Depot.
      </div>
      <div class="col-12-sm hidden-lg footer-images">
        <img src="https://secure.medicalsupplydepot.com/site/img/verisign_l.gif">
        <img src="https://images.scanalert.com/meter/www.medicalsupplydepot.com/13.gif" style="margin-top:5px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I got in Netsuite and working how I need it. Loads of trial and error. Regarding Bootstrap, I'll have a look at it and learn that. Now that submit button doesn't work so I need to get that sorted.